# could not determine version for package highcharts-angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am currently trying to get a highcharts-angular project to run.
Whenever I am using an npm command, i get following errors:

```
npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.4 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@^8.0.0-beta.0 || ^8.1.0-beta.0 || ^8.2.0-beta.0 || ^8.3.0-beta.0 || ^8.4.0-beta.0 || >=9.0.0-beta < 9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@8.3.4 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@^8.0.0-beta.0 || ^8.1.0-beta.0 || ^8.2.0-beta.0 || ^8.3.0-beta.0 || ^8.4.0-beta.0 || >=9.0.0-beta < 9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@8.3.4 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.4 < 3.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN injection-js@2.2.2 requires a peer of tslib@^1.9.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-packagr@4.4.0 requires a peer of tsickle@>=0.27.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsickle@0.25.5 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/ng-packagr/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/karma/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

so I tried running the command `ng update` but then this error turned up:

> An unexpected error happened; could not determine version for package
>   highcharts-angular.

What could be the solution here?

Comment: Share package.json file too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-install the latest highcharts versions.

```
npm install highcharts-angular --save
npm install highcharts --save
```